# Do the mastery "Evasion" applies against Karthus's Requiem?

Tags: league-of-legends

The skill evasion do the following:

> Reduces the damage taken from area effect abilities by 1/2/3%

Does it reduce the damage from [Karthus's Requiem](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Karthus_the_Deathsinger) ?

> **Requiem** (Active): After channeling for 3 seconds, Karthus deals magic damage to all enemy champions regardless of the distance.

In the [Wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect) there is no example for Requiem.

> There exist a various amount of AoE champion abilities, summoner
>   spells, and effect-granting items in the game and they can all be put
>   in the following categories:
>
> - [Chain](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect#Chain)
> - [Cone](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect#Cone)
> - [Ground targeted](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect#Ground_targeted)
> - [Line](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect#Line)
> - [Point blank](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect#Point_blank)
> - [Single targeted](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect#Single_targeted)
> - [Hybrid](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Area_of_effect#Hybrid)

Comment: I Submited it to the Rift Myths too. If/when I got an reply (or if they link a video) I'll post it here.

Comment: The answers doesn't have any real source. There is only  assumptions and beliefs about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright,
The awesome FallenAngelEyes helped me do some science and here are the results:

With Evasion:

[image]

Without Evasion:

[image]

As you can see, Requiem does not get reduced by the Evasion mastery.

I ran the same set up for Karthus both times (gear, runes, and masteries).

Comment: @FAE You totally should earn a "Science Assistant" badge for things like this.

Comment: @Rapida Hahaha, yeah this is like the 3rd time I've been a willing victim in the name of LoL science.

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference between Area of Effect abilities and Multi-Target abilities. Things like [Ahri](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Ahri_the_9_Tails_Fox)'s Fox Fire and [Vladimir](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Vladimir_the_Crimson_Reaper)'s Tides of Blood at Multi-Target abilities while something like [Amumu](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nasus_the_Curator_of_the_Sands)'s Tantrum or [Nasus](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Nasus_the_Curator_of_the_Sands)'s Spirit fire. Basically Area of Effect spells target a location on the map while Multi-Target spells target multiple champions or units.

Since Evasion states that it reduces damage from Area of Effect abilities I think we can assume that it **does not reduce the damage from Karthus's Ult (Requiem) since that is a Multi-Target spell.**

Comment: I tend to agree with you @Roving. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any source to back this up.

Comment: When I can get a friend to waste 30 minutes with me, I'll test this out in a custom game and post results here.

Comment: Good point. But as you said, is not sure about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume AoE would be skills that inflict or cause some kind of effect to multiple characters at one time in general